# Mistake in the X-Men movies regarding Charles Xavier's handicap?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine, x-men-first-class, x-men-the-last-stand

I think there's something wrong in the *X-Men* movies.

In *X-Men: First Class*, Charles Xavier is paralysed and loses control of his legs even before he starts the school for gifted youngsters.

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, at the end of the movie, he is seen walking towards young Scott and talking to him via his mind.

Then, in *X-Men: The Last Stand*, it flashes back 20 years, and you see the grown-up Xavier and Magneto, friends, talking to a young Jean Grey.

This is a total contradiction right?

Comment: Yes. It's a known plot hole in the movies.

Comment: Though, Singer has said that the next movie will do a lot to correct some of these issues and inconsistencies.

Comment: And even in the comics, Xavier has regained and lost the use of his legs multiple times.